# Flex: center Window?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to center a launched window in flex, there is a NativeWindow.x and NativeWindow.y but flex uses the Window class which does not have these properties, so does anyone know how to center a window? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
window.nativeWindow.x = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width - window.width)/2;
window.nativeWindow.y = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height - window.height)/2;
```

I think you have to call this AFTER window.open() though.

Comment: Hehe... you have answered your question.
From what I know... this is the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use

`nativeWindow.x = (Capabilities.screenResolutionX - nativeWindow.width) / 2;
nativeWindow.y = (Capabilities.screenResolutionY - nativeWindow.height) / 2;`

Seems to work well

Answer (score 1):

isn't this better?

example docs:

```
// center the window on the screen
var screenBounds:Rectangle = Screen.mainScreen.bounds;
nativeWindow.x = (screenBounds.width - nativeWindow.width) / 2;
nativeWindow.y = (screenBounds.height - nativeWindow.height) / 2;
```

[from livedocs: about window containers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=FlexApolloComponents_16.html)
¨

both solutions worked for me even on multiple screen system (Win7)

Answer (score 0):

actually this works better in flex 4.5 and above

```
nativeWindow.x = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width - nativeWindow.width)/2;
nativeWindow.y = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height - nativeWindow.height)/2;
```